# gatsby-source-mysql only returns one result

Tags: mysql, gatsby

I am trying to create a small gatsby-site on which I need to query a database. So using `gatsby-source-mysql` i have connected to my database and queried a table.

Using Graph*i*QL i only ever get the last row as a result.
My query:

```
query MyQuery {
  allMysqlForm {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        alias
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allMysqlForm": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "mysql__Form__undefined",
            "alias": "alias-of-the-last-entry-in-table"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, GraphQL needs an `id` to create a schema from your data. As it's inferred from:

```
"id": "mysql__Form__undefined",
```

Your `id` is `undefined`, or in other words, all your entries of your table have the same `id`, that's why you are getting the last row because the schema is overrated for each result.

Add a custom `id` in your database.

Comment: Is the ID a column named ID? My Database does have one of those with unique Numbers as Identifiers.

Comment: You can call and alias it as you wish in your GraphQL query